# Add on to a nested object via Object.assign

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Let's say I have an object

```
   let sampleObject = {
        "child1": [
            {"id": "id1"},
            {"id": "id2"}
        ]
    };
```

Is there a way to add another nested property after sampleObject has already been declared?

I want sampleObject to look like

```
    sampleObject = {
        "child1": [
            {"id": "id1"},
            {"id": "id2"}
         ],
        "child2":[
            {"id": "id3"}
         ]
            };
```

I tried something like 
Object.assign(sampleObject, "child2": [ "id" : "id3" ]); of which is giving syntax errors.

I guess my question is if this is possible via Object.assign and if not, how can I do so?

Thank you!

Comment: The second argument to `Object.assign` should be the key, the third the value. `Object.assign(sampleObject, "child2",  [{ "id" : "id3" }]);` Don't put a colon between the second and third argument, use a comma, and use brackets `{ ... }` to indicate an object literal

Comment: Over-complicating it...just do `sampleObject.child2 =  [{"id" : "id3" }]`

Comment: When I try sampleObject.child2 = [{"id" : "id3" }], I get the error, Property 'child2' does not exist on type {"child1":{"id":string;}[];}

Answer (score 0):

So there's multiple ways you can do this.  The most straightforward way is just adding a new property manually.

```js
const sampleObject = {
  child1: [
    {id: 'id1'},
    {id: 'id2'}
  ]
}

sampleObject.child2 = [{id: 'id3'}]
```

If this doesn't work in your circumstance, you could try `Object.defineProperty()`. [read more about Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

```js
const sampleObject = {
  child1: [
    {id: 'id1'},
    {id: 'id2'}
  ]
}

Object.defineProperty(sampleObject, 'child2', {
  value: [{id: 'id3'}]
})
```

Finally, if you want to use `Object.assign()` you can, but this is mostly for merging two or more objects.  This is a good way to provide defaults, and then optionally override them. [read more about Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
const sampleObject = {
  child1: [
    {id: 'id1'},
    {id: 'id2'}
  ]
}

const sampleObject2 = {
  child2: [
    {id: 'id3'}
  ]
}

Object.assign(sampleObject, sampleObject2)
```

Update: as mentioned by @Ryan Nghiem, you can also use the spread operator (`...`) in a similar way, though I would discourage reassigning the original variable.  This will "spread" out each property from the original object as properties of the new one. [read more about the spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
const sampleObject = {
  child1: [
    {id: 'id1'},
    {id: 'id2'}
  ]
}

const sampleObject2 = {
  ...sampleObject,
  child2: [
    {id: 'id3'}
  ]
}
```

Comment: I found for some reason doing it like this sampleObject["child2"] = [{"id":"id3"}]; works for me.  However, if I wanted another value for child2, such as sampleObject["child2"] = [{"id":"id4"}];, it overrides sampleObject, and only shows id4 and not both id3 and id4

Comment: Yes, `sampleObject.child2` and `sampleObject["child2"]` are both valid ways of getting and setting the property `child2` of the object `sampleObject`.  When you assign `child2` to any value using the `=` assignment operator, you override the previous value with the new one.  Instead of thinking about the object, think about the property.  It's the same as assigning `var child2 = [{id: 'id3'}]` and then `var child2 = [{id: 'id4'}]`.  This is new value instead of old value, not new value *plus* old value.  If you want to *add* an object to the array, try `sampleObject.child2.push({id: 'id2'})`.

Answer (score 0):

With ES6, you can use three dots `...`

```
sampleObject = {...sampleObject, {"child2": { "id" : "id3" }}
```